# IBM MQ Authentication and Authorization

Tags: authentication, authorization, ibm-mq, messaging

According to my current understanding, all the client connections are authenticated at two levels, channel level and queue manger level,

At the queue manager level, it uses the `CONNAUTH` property's value of the `QMGR` which is an `AUTHINFO` object to determine how the authentication is done (Ex: Using host OS user repo), if the `AUTHINFO` object specifies `ADOPTCTX(YES)`, it uses the user id contained in `MQCSP` structure as the user id for the application context and it is used for authorizations or if `ADOPTCTX(NO)` is there, the user id which the client application is running under is used as user id for the application context and that user id is used for authorizations.

At channel level, nothing regarding to authorizations is done. Only the authentication happens there as configured. For more granular access control, a set of channel authentication records are applied to the channels. `CONNAUTH` property's value of the `QMGR` is still used to determine the user repository to authenticate against.

**Questions:**

1. Am I correct up to this point? (corrections/explanations are much appreciated.)
2. What does the MCAUSER attribute of the channel object do? What is the purpose of it? Why does it matter which user the message channel agent runs under?
3. After all, how does the channel level authentication actually work with the MCAUSER?
4. In what order these two authentication procedures are done? Is the channel authentication done first?

Comment: The `MCAUSER` of the channel is overridden if you have `ADOPTCTX(YES)` and a username and password was presented and successfully authenticated.  If no username and password is provided then the `MCAUSER` will override the user the client app is running under.  If you don't have `CHKCLNT(REQUIRED)` either on the `QMGR AUTHINFO` object or via a `CHLAUTH` rule,  and you didn't have a `MCAUSER`, the client could spoof any user they want.   Default `CHLAUTH` rules will block MQ admin users by default.   Best practice would be to set `MCAUSER('*NOACCESS')` and let `CONNAUTH` override  it.

Comment: _This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only._

Comment: @Droid - it is two questions that cannot be thought about independently though - how do authentication and authorization interact.

Comment: @MoragHughson I voted to reopen.

Comment: Me too @JoshMc. Don't think it should have been closed in the first place. It is an excellent question and one many people are asking.

Comment: I voted to reopen it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that one should think about security of client connected MQ applications in two phases. There is an authentication phase (who are you? prove it!), and an authorization phase (now that I know who you are, are you allowed to do what you are trying to do?).

Authentication of a client connected MQ application can be done by checking the user id and password provided by the application (in the MQCSP) or by something at the channel level. This is essentially authenticating the channel connection, but it is inextricably linked to the client application. This channel authentication can use TLS certificates or a security exit to interrogate the remote party any way you feel like. [There is also IP address filtering but I wouldn't call that authentication so much].

The purpose of these authentications are to determine who the connecting party is (and reject them if necessary!) and to assign an appropriate user ID for the next step (the authorization checks). Assignment of this user ID can be done by accepting the password validated user ID (`ADOPTCTX(YES)`); by mapping certificate DNs (or IP addresses) using `CHLAUTH` rules; by setting the `MCAUSER` via a security exit; or by simply hard-coding a user ID into the `MCAUSER` (not authentication, but still a way to assign a user id for the later authorization checks). All of these have one thing in common, what they do ends up in the running `SVRCONN`'s `MCAUSER` field. You can display it using `DISPLAY CHSTATUS`.

Authorization of a client connected MQ application happens just as it does for a locally bound MQ application. The same operations are checked against the same rules. Is this user allowed to "Open this Queue for putting", or "Inquire this QMgr object", or "subscribe to this topic" etc. The difference is simply in how the user ID used in that authorization check is obtained - i.e. how it gets into the `MCAUSER`.

To wrap up (and check I have covered all your questions):-

1. Sort of - read above text
2. The `MCAUSER` attribute at run-time holds the finally determined user ID for this client application. At definition time it can be hard-coded to a user id (some people use this to hard-code a rubbish user id as a belt-and-braces along side the `CHLAUTH` backstop rule).
3. Channel level authentication essentially sets the run-time value of `MCAUSER`
4. Authentication happens before authorization.

**Further Reading**

- [CHLAUTH – the back-stop rule](https://mqgem.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/mq_chlauth_the_back_stop_rule/)
- [All the ways to set MCAUSER](https://mqgem.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/all-the-ways-to-set-mcauser/)
- [Interaction of CHLAUTH and CONNAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q132550_.html) - previously a blog post now incorporated into IBM Knowledge Center

Comment: If I understand it correctly, MCA user is the actual runtime user who is authorized to perform operations. An inbound client connection provides 2 user IDs, the user ID that the client app runs under and the user id provided in MQCSP along with a password. Using those incoming pieces of information, identification and authentication are done which finally leads to determining the runtime MCAUSER

Comment: Yes, I would add that the client may also provide a digital certificate which may also be used for identification and authentication and to ultimately determine the runtime MCAUSER